# How to map nested collections using MapStruct?

Tags: java, collections, mapstruct

I have 2 entities:

**Entity 1:**

```
public class Master {

    private int id;
    private Set<SubMaster> subMasters= new HashSet<SubMaster>(0);
}

public class SubMaster{
    private int subId;
    private String subName;
}
```

**Entity 2:**

```
public class MasterDTO {

    private int id;
    private Set<SubMaster> subMasters= new HashSet<SubMaster>(0);
}

public class SubMasterDTO{
    private int subId;
    private String subName;
}
```

I am using MapStruct Mapper to map values of POJO to another.

```
public interface MasterMapper{
    MasterDTO toDto(Master entity);
}
```

I am able to successfully map `Master` to `MasterDTO`. But, the nested collection of `SubMaster` in `Master` is not getting mapped to its counterpart in `MasterDTO`.

Could anyone help me in right direction?

Comment: Are you using version `1.2.0`? If yes then MapStruct should automatically create everything for you. Also you are missing `@Mapper` on your interface. Also your set in the `MasterDTO` is `SubMaster` and not `SubMasterDTO` (I am not sure if you have it like that in your code as well).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[This example](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/c0c0137a0222d92797c991a7e9755bfecb8bed04/mapstruct-field-mapping) in Mapstruct's Github repo is an exact showcase for what you're trying to do.

TL;DR You'll need a separate mapper for the `SubMaster` (let's call it `SubMasterMapper`) class and then put a `@Mapper(uses = { SubMasterMapper.class })` annotation on your `MasterMapper`:

```
public interface SubMasterMapper {
    SubMasterDTO toDto(SubMaster entity);
}

@Mapper(uses = { SubMasterMapper.class })
public interface MasterMapper {
    MasterDTO toDto(Master entity);
}
```