# Unmapped target property with mapstruct while converting an object to a Long

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I have a problem with mapstruct while converting an object to a Long, I have the following warning:

`warning: Unmapped target property`

Here are the entities (I an using Lombok):

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class User {
        ...
        private Set<Address> addresses= new HashSet<>();
        ...
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class Address {
        ...
        private Town town;
        ...
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class Town {
        ...
        private Long id;
        ...
    }
```

and DTOs:

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class UserDTO {
        ...
        private Set<AddressDTO> addresses= new HashSet<>();
        ...
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class AddressDTO {
        ...
        private Long townId;
        ...
    }
```

In addressDTO, I want townId instead of the town object. Here are the mappers:

```java
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDTO userToUserDTO(User user);

}

@Mapper
public interface AddressMapper {

    AddressMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AddressMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "townId", source = "town")
    AddressDTO addressToAddressDTO(Address address);

    default Long getTownId(Town town) {
        return town.getId();
    }
}
```

I wrote a unit test for AddressMapper that works:

```java
AddressDTO addressDTO = AddressMapper.INSTANCE.addressToAddresslDTO( address);
```

but it does not work for UserMapper :

```java
UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.INSTANCE.userToUserDTO( user);
```

I have the following warning:

```
warning: Unmapped target property: "townId". Mapping from Collection element "fr.example.myproj.entity.Adress adresses" to "fr.example.myproj.service.dto.AdressDTO adresses".
    UserDTO userToUserDTO(User user);
```

Comment: related question: [how to map nested collections using MapStruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45814147/5818405)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to reuse the `AddressMapper` in the `UserMapper` you can use `Mapping#uses`. That way the `AddressMapper#addressToAddressDTO` method would be detected by MapStruct automatically.

E.g.

```
@Mapper(uses = AddressMapper.class)
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDTO userToUserDTO(User user);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using [custom method to mapper](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods).

```java
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDTO userToUserDTO(User user);

    default AddressDTO addressToAddressDTO(Address address) {
        return AddressMapper.INSTANCE.addressToAdressDTO( address );
    }

}
```